# left outer join doesnt return all rows on left table

Tags: sql, left-join

```
 set @fuel_type='hsd';
select 
ro.ro_id,

(case
    when if(@fuel_type='ms',r.ms_field_input_id,r.hsd_field_input_id)= 0 
    then    if(@fuel_type='ms',concat(r.remark_ms,r.remark_branded),r.remark_hsd)
    else
    f.field_name
end )

from
retail_outlets ro left  join 
volume_trackers r on ro.ro_id=r.ro_id,
field_inputs_master f
where
    if(@fuel_type='ms',r.ms_field_input_id =   f.field_id,r.hsd_field_input_id=f.field_id) 
    and ro.pricing_module=1 and if(@fuel_type='ms',ro.ms,ro.hsd)=1 and      r.date_inserted='2017-02-06' 
    ;
```

I need to show all the ro_id in the retail_outlets table but only the ro_id that match with the volume trackers table are displayes

Comment: Move any where clause criteria from tables on the "Right side" of the left join to the join.  What's happening is those null values are being excluded because the limits in the where clause don't account for null values.  to put it another way, you where clause makes you left join behave like an inner join.  Specifically it looks like `r.date_inserted = '2017-02-06'` should be moved to the join critiera

Comment: And don't mix notations.  you really shouldn't be using `,` in the from clause anymore.

Comment: @xQbert i tried moving the r.date_inserted to the join criteria but it still didn't work

Comment: I don't think your query is doing what you think it's doing. Using the comma syntax for JOINing, I believe fields_input_master is INNER JOINing. That will change your final recordset. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not positive but I think this is what you're after.

changes are the following:

1. removed , notation and inject a left join
2. moved the r.date_inserted to the join criteria.
3. moved where clause for , join to new left join and altered to case statement  as to why I used a left join... Since we tie back to R which is already a left join it made sense to me to continue with left joins...
4. removed some unneeded ()'s

Assumptions r.date_inserted is a varchar2 data type or '2017-02-06' is implicitly being cast correctly.

.

```
SET @fuel_type='hsd';

SELECT
  ro.ro_id ,

    CASE
      WHEN IF(@fuel_type='ms',r.ms_field_input_id,r.hsd_field_input_id)= 0
      THEN IF(@fuel_type='ms',concat(r.remark_ms,r.remark_branded),r.remark_hsd)
      ELSE f.field_name
    END
FROM retail_outlets ro
LEFT JOIN volume_trackers r
   ON ro.ro_id = r.ro_id
  AND r.date_inserted  = '2017-02-06'
LEFT JOIN field_inputs_master f
   ON f.field_id = CASE WHEN @fuel_type='ms' 
                        THEN r.ms_field_input_id 
                        ELSE r.hsd_field_input_id 
                   END
WHERE ro.pricing_module=1
  AND IF(@fuel_type    ='ms',ro.ms,ro.hsd)=1;
```

Comment: i cant write the f.field after field_inputs_master f

Comment: forgot keyword `on`.

Comment: still not working what is f.field that you have added?

Comment: f.field should have been f.field_ID  it's from your original `if(@fuel_type='ms',r.ms_field_input_id =   `f.field_id`,r.hsd_field_input_id=`f.field_id`) `  note both formulas compare to f.field_id so i abstracted that part out for readability. but spelled f.field_id wrong.

Comment: Something positive should be getting 114 rows now with your query i am getting 57 rows

Comment: odd that the number is exactly 1/2....  Are you sure the 114 is right?  Start removing limiting criteria the and r.date_inserted or the where clause to see if somethings being excluded that shouldn't be.  If you know it should be 114. compare the data sets to figure out what's in the 114 not in the 57 and we can work it from there .

Comment: I'd need to see sample data that is expected not in our 57 to figure out what's going on at this point.

Comment: well its difficult for me to post the data here

Comment: and sorry i read it wrong i am only able to see 51 rows not 57

Comment: Does `Select * FROM retail_outlets ro
LEFT JOIN volume_trackers r
   ON ro.ro_id = r.ro_id
LEFT JOIN field_inputs_master f
   ON f.field_id = CASE WHEN @fuel_type='ms' 
                        THEN r.ms_field_input_id 
                        ELSE r.hsd_field_input_id 
                   END` include all the 114 records needed and more?  if so then one of the 3 limiting criteria is causing the records to be excluded.  If not, then the query itself is still not correct and without some examples I wouldn't know where to begin.  3 limites are: 2 in where 1 on join.

Comment: How many rows do you get with a simple select from the retail_outlets table (with your ro filters)?

Comment: @xQbert thanks your initial query actually worked.I thought i was checking for fuel_type'ms' but i had set fuel_type hsd so the value that i was looking for is 51 so your query worked..Thanks for your help